# Sharepoint Online- Creating a footer

Tags: office365, footer, sharepoint-online

How can I create a footer using the term store like the one on https://www.microsoft.com/en-in/. How can include that in the mastepage so that it reflects across the site. Please help...

Answer (score 0):

For modern view, you could create SPFx [Application Customizer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/extensions/get-started/using-page-placeholder-with-extensions)  for this.

For classic view, you could inject custom JavaScript logic by [Add-PnPJavaScriptLink](https://github.com/SharePoint/PnP-Guidance/blob/master/powershell/AddPnPJavaScriptLink.md)